# Can I browse the web using the UDP protocol?

Tags: http, openvpn, udp

Is it possible to browse the web if a firewall is blocking the HTTP protocol?

I've read about OpenVPN UDP tunnelling, but is it possible to use the web via the UDP protocol?

Answer (score 2):

I have NEVER seen a firewall that blocks **all** HTTP traffic, whereas 99.9% of them block all UDP traffic and **some** HTTP traffic (e.g. website blacklisting).

If your firewall *selectively* blocks some HTTP traffic, you can make a fool of it by using OpenVPN over TCP towards port 443 of the remote server (see [SwissVPN](http://www.swissvpn.net/)). It will put all of your traffic into an SSL socket and no firewall will distinguish it from HTTPS traffic towards an unknown host, because SSL on 443 == HTTPS for the eavesdropper. But if the block is white-list based, then you have no chances.

Can you better describe the firewall we're talking about?

Comment: Network is blocking all tcp so only way is udp.

Comment: I see, even if this firewall is total nonsense. However, I think that using OpenVPN over UDP will work, but I cannot suggest you any out-of-the-box solution, whereas for OpenVPN over TCP I could (see SwissVPN). I'll search further.